# Converting into a string each of the lines retrieved from reading a text file

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion, buffer

How can convert into a string each of the lines retrieved from reading a text file. For instance:

```
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("C:text.txt", "r");
    FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
    System.out.println("Size: " + channel.size());
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
    channel.read(buffer);
    buffer.flip();//Restore buffer to position 0 to read it
    System.out.println("Read ... ");


    for (int i = 0; i < channel.size(); i++) {                     

        System.out.print((char) buffer.get());

    }
```

I tried to add the following inside the for loop to get each line each time in "stringValueOf" but instead it displays each caracter separatly and not each line.

```
 String stringValueOf = String.valueOf((char) buffer.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

InputStreamReader is used to read characters. Java provides BufferedReader to make reading lines easy.

The following snippet reads lines from file and prints to standard output.

```
public void printFileLinesToStdOut(File file, Charset charSet)
{
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), charSet)))
    {
        String line = null;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         // TODO : your code here
    }
}
```